# Detect AC(on/off) and Window(open/close) of CAR using OBD

Tags: ac, obd-ii

**Is there any way to detect AC(air conditioner) and Window(open/close) using OBD?**

I am putting links below for the OBD reader but I am unable to find any way to detect the AC(air conditioner) and Window state (open/close).

https://github.com/pires/obd-java-api

https://github.com/pires/android-obd-reader

Comment: Thanks @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing . Check my updated question.

Comment: As I understand you want to read whether the AC is on or off and which windows are opened and closed via OBD? I don't think there are such PIDs defined by the SAE J1939 standard. That doesn't mean your vehicle does not support these, some manufacturers add extra PIDs. However I personally haven't seen them available before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those OBD-II PIDS are **NOT** part of the standard OBD-II spec - they are manufacturer specific and not governed under OBD-II

That being said, I know for a fact that you can get this data if your car is a Daihatsu Copen as I have done it